# Cannot find module 'lodash/isString'

Tags: ethereum, web3js

This error happened to me overnight. I'm no longer able to retrieve Decentraland data from the chain. I've attempted to upgrade the dependency in the web3-core-method nodemodule, but to no avail.

From my package.json:

```
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.41"
```

Here is the full error:

```
 Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/isString'
[0]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
[0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/project/node_modules/web3-core-method/dist/web3-core-method.cjs.js:12:32)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
[0]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
[0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
[0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/project/node_modules/web3-eth-accounts/dist/web3-eth-accounts.cjs.js:10:22)
[0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
[0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
[0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

- NPM: 6.4.1
- Node: 10.14.2

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Converting OP's commented solution to an answer:</sub>

> I fixed this by going into the web3-core-method package.json and adding in lodash as a dependency.
> – [Sm00g15](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10987741/sm00g15) on [Feb 5, 2019 at 1:56](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509878/cannot-find-module-lodash-isstring#comment95855716_54509878)